# Issue with gedit printing

Tags: 12.04, printing, gedit

I executed `gedit` and printed some texts with it in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

But I think that It's not doing it correctly.

[image: Print on gedit]

[image: empyt paper]

Perhaps I don't know how to use `gedit`.

Please help me with the way how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try printing? Did it work?